# MySQL - Decimal cannot be NULL

Tags: php, mysql

Everytime I try to make an insert statement into my dastabase I get a "Incorrect decimal value: 'NULL' for column 'bounty3' at row 1" error.  How do I insert a null value into a decimal datatype?  Should I just make the default value 0.00?

```
Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'bounty3' at row 1 Whole query: INSERT INTO songs (userid, wavURL, mp3URL, genre, songTitle, BPM, insWanted, bounty, insWanted2, bounty2, insWanted3, bounty3, insWanted4, bounty4, insWanted5, bounty5, insWanted6, bounty6, insWanted7, bounty7, insWanted8, bounty8, insWanted9, bounty9, insWanted10, bounty10) VALUES ('12534545', '/audio/wav/jqmrgpfcMichael/135259578210secreason.wav', '/audio/mp3/jqmrgpfcMichael/135259578210secreason.mp3', 'Rock/Funk', 'titlee', '120', 'bass', '20.00', 'guitar', '20.00', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')
```

I tried this statement with a NULL value too.  Here is the error:

```
Incorrect decimal value: 'NULL' for column 'bounty3' at row 1 Whole query: INSERT INTO songs (userid, wavURL, mp3URL, genre, songTitle, BPM, insWanted, bounty, insWanted2, bounty2, insWanted3, bounty3, insWanted4, bounty4, insWanted5, bounty5, insWanted6, bounty6, insWanted7, bounty7, insWanted8, bounty8, insWanted9, bounty9, insWanted10, bounty10) VALUES ('12534545', '/audio/wav/jqmrgpfcMichael/143922765110secreason.wav', '/audio/mp3/jqmrgpfcMichael/143922765110secreason.mp3', 'Rock/Funk', 'title', '110', 'bass', '110.00', 'guitar', '20.00', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL')
```

Comment: Can you please give paste the code/mysql statement which inserts the data.

Comment: Make sure your table definition allows NULL values for that column. If that doesn't help show us your code and your data definition.

Comment: I have updated with my insert statement.  I erased the 'NULL' value and now I'm getting this error.

Comment: see edits in my answer -- may be that would help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use blank, not null, if you want the default value.

Comment: -1 If you declare the column with a default value, inserting `null` will trigger the default to be used. The OP has **not** declared a default on a `not null` column therefore an error is issued. Inserting blank `''` **does not** insert the default value. It inserts `0`.

Comment: Still -1, but apparently the OP is inserting `'null'` into the decimal and expecting MySQL to see it is `null` and not a string filled with n.u.l.l.

Answer (score 17):

Oh.. you are trying to insert an empty string '' into bounty3. Replace it with NULL. I have also noticed empty strings for other possible numeric values eg bonty4. You should replace all empty strings with NULL for numeric values.

eg: mysql_query("INSERT INTO empty_number,number VALUES(NULL,1)");

**EDIT**: HEY HEY get the point, you cannot insert NULL to a numeric value as 'NULL' because this is a string, you should insert as NULL without any quotation marks

Answer (score 3):

I just dealt with this issue in MySql 5.1.61.
If the server is in strict mode, you must enter 0 instead of '' for decimal fields. Disabling strict mode allows you to just do '' to populate a null value.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, it worked using NULL when it comes empty:

```
$conn->bindParam(':'.$valor, ( $key[0] ? $key[0] : NULL ), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run this query to allow NULL values in 'bounty3' field.

ALTER TABLE `songs` CHANGE `bounty3` `bounty3` DECIMAL(10,0)  NULL;

Comment: I am allowing NULL on this field.  It just doesn't seem to work for a decimal datatype (which I believe I need for financial transactions...)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the field type allows for `NULL` values and that the default is `NULL`.

Then use:

```
UPDATE table_name SET date_field=IF('$date_value'='',NULL,'$date_value')
```

This works for inserts or updates.

I have tried using `$date_value = NULL` and I have even tried `unset($date_value)` before inserting or updating, and it never worked on my decimal fields. MySQL always converted them to 0.00. The method above was the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that the field is "nullable" (does not have `NOT NULL` in its definition)
2. Make field's default value NULL.

   Ex.: `price decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL`
3. Now, to test it, store some number, then '' (an empty string) into this field — it should become NULL in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The field is most likely numeric. If the field is numeric then only numbers are accepted. Empty string is not accepted

```
insert into songs (...,bounty3) values(...,'')
```

neither the NULL string

```
insert into songs (...,bounty3) values(...,'NULL')
```

('NULL' which is just a string, nothing to do with the actual NULL value, so 'NULL' si similar to 'HONEY BEE' if you want).

So if the column is numeric then it will only take numbers. However if the column is NULLABLE then it will accept NULL, too. That means your insert must have

```
insert into songs (...,bounty3) values (..., NULL)
```

If you push NULL on such a column and the column has a default value then DEFAULT value will be used instead of the NULL you are pushing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your database schema allows NULL values for that column. Run `describe <tablename>;` in your MySQL client to see what the schema for that table is.

If the schema does not allow null then you can use `alter table` to change the schema. Make sure you don't specify `NOT NULL` for that column and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make sure that in your source data, the empty cells or fields contain 'NULL' before you import them in MySQL. This way, MySQL will recognize these fields as being *really* NULL, and won't transform them to 0's.

Answer (score 0):

It worked por me when POST data is received:
...
if ($value == '') {$value = '0.0';}
...